# jquery fancybox error 'type'

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to use fancybox with my MVC application for the popup ability for videos and etc but when I click my links that I've created to use fancybox I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'type' 
jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6, line 2 character 131
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this issue?

Code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            helpers: {
                media: {}
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="list">
<li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example from [fancybox tips & tricks](http://fancybox.net/blog) n°4 :

```
$("#tip4").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

I guess you need to indicate

```
'type': 'swf',
```

And maybe swf options too.
I suggest you keep the

```
'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
```

Comment: Well that's the reason I picked the media helper so I wouldn't have to define those extra variables.

Comment: Right, you should have mentionned you're using FB2 (and not the 1st one)... or are you ?

Comment: Well the portion of the fancybox.js that it's blowing up on is:

    isString = function(str) {
   return $.type(str) === "string";
  },

Comment: Yes I'm on FB2, didn't know there was a iteration before.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: @1tufgt Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: The latest version, 1.7.2

Looks like i tried it with 1.7 and it popped up fine, do you think it's a issue with jquery 1.7.2?  Would 1.7.1 work?

Comment: Well it looks like the reason it doesn't work is that the jquery is not physically called on the page, but rather I have the jquery in my master page.  If I add the jquery script loading to that page it works fine except for the errors below:

But with it on the same page as where the code would exist it does work but when closing the video I get a bunch of errors `code`__flash__removeCallback(document.getElementById("video-player-flash"), "addEventListener");`code`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/pGRRj/1/ 
Maybe you could show your page?